# OrderBy With A Secondary Sub Sort

Tags: mysql

I have a query that I need to build that sorts items by a matching priority; however, when there are instances where I have a duplicate product, I'd like it to be grouped with highest priority on the initial match.   Not sure if this is possible or not in MySQL out of the gate or if I need to post process this in PHP or JS.

```
+-------+----------+---------+
| order_id | Priority | Product |
+-------+----------+---------+
| 12345 |        1 |  334455 |
| 12345 |        1 |  212121 |
| 12355 |        2 |  666666 |
| 12356 |        3 |  212121 |
| 12360 |        4 |  777777 |
+-------+----------+---------+
```

What I have tried and it fails of course.  I tried using "FIELD()" and does the same thing.

```sql
SELECT Order_id, Priority, Product FROM Products ORDER BY Priority ASC, Product
```

**Desired Result**

```
+-------+----------+---------+
| Order_id | Priority | Product |
+-------+----------+---------+
| 12345 |        1 |  334455 |
| 12345 |        1 |  212121 |
| 12356 |        3 |  212121 |
| 12355 |        2 |  666666 |
| 12360 |        4 |  777777 |
+-------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: Define 'fails'.

Comment: It returns the results sorted by priority and then the product within the priority.  This is not what i want.  I want it to sort by priority unless it has a like product.  See desired result

Comment: @sidu its just an example.  order_id

Comment: From your desired result, it is not sorted by order_id, nor by priority, nor by product, so what do you want to sort ?

Comment: @SIDU, you can see from the desired result. First is to sort by `Priority` BUT if there's a duplicate `product` value, those need to be shown one after the other, but maintain the priority ordering between the duplicates.

Comment: @tcadidot0 -- no. your expected result is NOT sort by anything

Comment: The sorting doesn't make sense, and if you tried anything, you won't be able to construct a simple query in trying to achieve the desired result. I think from OP's perspective, there's a reason why the desired result is like that. Furthermore, I've tried a few ways and I end up with a working query but I can't say for sure that the query is usable for other than returning OP's desired result. I myself have a few question over the query I made

Comment: @tcadidot0 can you post up your query?  I'd like to play with what you came up with it.   The use case is actually for a production flow, batch process manufacturing on single piece workflow.  This allows for products in order of when the order come in but then group subsequent products on future orders for the same day, say, with the same parts.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
select order_id, Priority, Product,
    (select min(Priority) from Products p1 where p.product = p1.product) as MinPrior
from Products p
order by MinPrior asc, Product asc, Priority asc;
```

I know, it's not exactly the same as the one in the "Desired Result", but if I understood the problem correctly, it does what the task required.

I hope, I could be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

I removed my first suggestion and post a query where I can be a bit certain about the results:

```
SELECT v.Order,v.Priority,v.Product,
       CASE WHEN priority < b_prio OR priority > b_prio AND product=b_prod THEN 1 
            WHEN priority=1 AND  product=b_prod THEN 0 
            WHEN priority <> 1 AND  product=b_prod THEN 2 END custom_rank FROM
     (SELECT a.*,
             IFNULL(b.order,a.order) b_order,
             IFNULL(b.product,a.product) b_prod,
             IFNULL(b.priority,a.priority) b_prio
        FROM products a LEFT JOIN products b 
          ON a.product=b.product AND a.priority <> b.priority) v 
ORDER BY custom_rank, priority;
```

So, the idea is to create a custom ranking. The query above will produce the following:
[image]

I did a self `LEFT JOIN` on `products` table to switch the priority in `b_prio` if the conditions `ON a.product=b.product AND a.priority <> b.priority` are met. `IFNULL` will take value from `products a` instead. Then from the outer query, I created a custom ranking from the `CASE` expression. With that I perform `ORDER BY custom_rank, priority;` and can get your desired result.